# Регулярное выражение дробное число или дробное число с % знаком

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Не могу придумать и завершить идею.
У меня проблема что правило на вод точки не работает, я могу вести больше одного раза знак точка или запятая.

Мой вариант который работает, но есть ошибки в нем. Я пробовал заменить все найденые варианты, ничего не работает. Надо такого вида чтоб была запись

```
onkeyup="this.value = this.value.replace (/^\d+(?:[.,]\d{1,2}%?)?$/g, '')"
```

**Идея**
input поле можно вести число дробное но оно может быть и проценое число, для опредление этого  конце потавить знак %.

Тесты на проверку

true

```
10 
8.6
10.3%
150.5
23.23
500.5%
```

false

```
.2%
.20%
..20
..20%
12.444
12.444%
12. 12
10%%
```

Желатально чтоб работа все из такого условия сразу. Если надо выносить в функцию и через ее прогонять, тогда пример 100% рабочий покажите, просто регулярку кинуть без возможности проверить на живом примере нету смысла. Я такие регулярные выражение находил а заставить работать не возмонжо.

```
<input  type="text" onkeyup="this.value = this.value.replace (/[^\d+(,|\.)?\d{0,2}%]+/g, '')">
```

Comment: Подскажите, что вы попробовали для решения этой проблемы?

Comment: Попробуйте воспользоваться сайтом https://regex101.com/r/aoDKLT/1 для настройки вашего регулярного выражения, по ссылке написал свой пример: `^\d+(?:[.,]\d{1,2}%?)?$`

Comment: @ipatev_nn не работает. Ведь заменив ваш вариант на мой какой написан он не работает вообще, полностью пропускает все. Просто сказать что это работает, без примера input не имеет смысла

Comment: @Pavel8289 Мне кажется, Вы не улавливаете разницу между проверкой на соответствие шаблону, и заменой по шаблону

Comment: Да и задача не так тривиальна, как может показаться. Например, вы ввели `10.`, данное значение не пройдет тест, а значит дальнейший ввод будет невозможен, хотя мы хотели `10.5`.

Comment: Почему они `12.444` и `12.444%` не валидные?

Comment: @EzioMercer числел после запятой должо быть 2

Comment: @Laukhin Andrey согласен

Answer (score 0):

Можете попробовать так, но единнственная загвоздка - это если человек введёт `5.` и решит на этом остановиться, тогда вам надо будет обработать этот случай во время сабмита (например добавить `0` в конце):

```js
const input = document.querySelector('#input');
const regexp = /^\d+(\.\d{0,2})?%?$/;

let oldValue = input.value;

input.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
  const newValue = e.target.value;
  
  if (regexp.test(newValue) || newValue === '') input.value = oldValue = newValue;
  else input.value = oldValue;
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input">
```

Answer (score 0):

Предложу более универсальный вариант, при этом достаточно простой.
Шаблон на проверку задаем в атрибуте `pattern` элемента `input`. В этом случае, чтобы мы не ввели в поле, браузер перед отправкой формы сделает проверку.
При этом мы можем дать пользователю понять ошибку, подсвечивая поле, например, красным. Дополнительно можно ограничить ввод неразрешенных символов.
Компромиссный вариант, который настраивается под любые правила:

```js
const symbols = /[\d.,%]/;
let input = document.getElementById('input');

input.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  if (e.key.length == 1 && !symbols.test(e.key)) e.preventDefault();
});

input.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
  this.checkValidity() ?
    this.style.backgroundColor = 'white' :
    this.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
});
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return false">
  <input id="input" type="text" pattern="^\d+(?:[.,]\d{1,2})?%?$" />
  <button>Отправить</button>
</form>
```

Можно сделать дополнительную проверку при потере фокуса, чтобы вынудить пользователя исправить ошибку.